# Solidity chainlink/AggregatorV3Interface decimals() returns number 8 always

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink

Hi i am learning Solidity and trying to get token price using chainlink/AggregatorV3Interface.I get it but when i try to get exactly price with decimals it returns 8.
this is my contract

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe{

mapping(address => uint256) public adressToAmountFunded;

function fund() public payable{
adressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}  

function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);
    return priceFeed.version();
}

function getPrice() public view returns(uint256,uint8){
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);

    (uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
     uint8 decimals = priceFeed.decimals();
    return  (uint256(answer), decimals);
      
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decimals() returns the number of decimals in the returned price. In this case, it is eight. I changed your getPrice() function a bit to exclude the use of decimals()

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe{

 mapping(address => uint256) public adressToAmountFunded;

 function fund() public payable{
  adressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
 }  

 function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
  AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);
  return priceFeed.version();
 }

 function getPrice() public view returns(uint256,uint8){
  AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);

  (uint80 roundId,
   int256 answer,
   uint256 startedAt,
   uint256 updatedAt,
   uint80 answeredInRound) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
  return(uint256(answer));    
 }
}
```

Let's say the current price of MATIC/USD is $2.378

getPrice() will return 237800000, where the eight last digits are the decimals.

You can also simplify the code a bit since it seems like you won't need some of the items returned. This way you won't store unnecessary variables. Replace getPrice() with this

```
 function getPrice() public view returns(uint256,uint8){
  AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);

  (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
  return(uint256(answer));    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The decimals value represents the number of decimal places in the answer and will always be the same. For this feed always posts answer that go out 8 decimal places.